# Syncing with iTunes - saving iPhone app resources

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I have an app in the app store which a database in the resources folder. I've updated the app several times and the database is still preserved from update to update, which is good.

My question is, if a user syncs their phone with iTunes, and then they get a new phone, and put the app back on the the new phone, will the resources (including this databse) in my app be saved?

Or will the app lose all the user data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data will be saved/written to the new phone.  That's the whole point of syncing.

Comment: As long as the database is stored under Documents or Library (excluding Library/Caches).